# where can I find a pyHook module compatible with python 3.7

Tags: python

I have for two days been trying to install pyHook and i cannot seem to find one which is compatible with python 3.7, is it available and if yes where can I find it and if not how what can I do to get the one for previous versions to work on

Answer (score 1):

A simple `pip search pyhook` gives:

```
pyHook (1.5.1)              - pyHook: Python wrapper for out-of-context input hooks in Windows
pyHook-3k-compiled (1.5.1)  - pyHook: Python wrapper for out-of-context input hooks in Windows
mypyHook (1.5.2)            - A pyHook module from parlente for my personal use
pyWinhook (1.6.1)           - A pyHook module fork from Peter P. with some updates.
pyhooked (0.8.1)            - Pure Python hotkey hook, with thanks to pyHook, pywinauto, and pyhk
```

A little testing show that the last two **both** install successfully into Python 3.7 on Windows 10 with the usual `pip install` command.
[image: pip install pyhooked]
[image: pip install pyWinhook]

Comment: The newest version is from 2008. How does this answer cover the question’s compatibility issues with Python 3.7?

Comment: @EricShain: I should have suggested testing and especially considering pyhooked as it is pure python so the most likely to be version independent as long as it has been updated to python 3.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn’t able to find any indication on PyHook’s site indicating Python 3.7 compatibility.

Comment: pyHook has any support at now? For keyboard controlling I've found keyboard module. pip install keyboard, and doc: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api

Comment: @Znik My suggestion is to use `pip  install pyhooked` as a Python 3 compatible alternative to pyHook